# VB,NET program marked as PUP by McAfee

Tags: vb.net, mcafee, pup

I've been delivering new versions of our VB.NET program to our clients via FTP for many years. Now one of the programs get stopped by the clients McAfee antivirus witch claims it to be a PUP (Potentially Unwanted Program) The only change from the version that the client could download is that it's compiled for 64bit CPU.

Other programs compiled for 64bit can be downloaded and there is just one of them that is stopped. Is there anyone that knows how to get your program of the list?

/POE

Comment: Contact McAfee. They're the ones who make the list.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add your filename to the McCrappy exception list
2) Sign your file (not self signing certificate but a reputable code signer).

Comment: And suddenly the file isn't stopped, it's possible to get file without any problems. It must be a McCrappy problem ;)